# Python CLR Winforms - DataRowView object returns as values in a ComboBox

Tags: python, .net, winforms, clr, ironpython

All,

When using Python CLR (IronPython) to populate a ComboBox using the DataSource method, my data returns as a bunch of separate **System.Data.DataRowView** objects.

How do I turn those into the values? I am sure I am missing something simple.

[image]

Current code is below:

```
def LoadDensityComboBox(self, Query):
    self.PopulateData(Query)
        
    # Load the data into the DensityName combobox
    self.cboDensityName.DataSource = self.data_table
    print(type(self.cboDensityName.DataSource))
    
def PopulateData(self, Query):
    # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Z4BGEHD-JQ --> 50:00 MINUTE MARK - Use this for SELECT queries

    try:
        sqlConn = SqlConnection(CONN_STR) # removed for security purposes
        
        sqlConn.Open()
    
        # Create Command
        cmd = SqlCommand(Query, sqlConn)
    
        # Execute the command and fill the dataset
        self.data_table = DataTable()
        da = SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(self.data_table)
        
        return self.data_table

    except:
        MessageBox.Show("Something happened.")
    
    finally:
        if sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open:
            sqlConn.Close
```

Comment: Specify `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` (if needed) of your `cboDensityName`, otherwise the items collection is generated with something like `foreach (var o in [DataSource].AsEnumerable()) { [Items Collection].Add(o.ToString()); }`. Hence each `o` returns the Type name, which is `DataRowView` here

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for that. Setting the DisplayMember property was the key.